# Nexenta (Solaris), strange user membership from LDAP

Tags: linux, solaris, ldap, opensolaris, nexenta

Why do run id command in the Nexenta OS (Solaris+Ubuntu), I get different result?

```
a_ay@nexenta:/etc$ id -G
513 512 1000 201 203 1010 1013 1019 1020 1036 1039 1040 1041 1045 1046 1047

a_ay@nexenta:/etc$ id -G a_ay
513 1019 1041 1047 512 1039 1036 201 3333 1000 1013 1020 1046 1057 1100 1040 1045 1048 203 1010
```

Moreover, I'm having a membership in one of the secondary group (1048) and I can not enter to the folder 'Folder' with  GID permission is 1048.

```
drw-r-xr-x 1 1062 1048       0 Apr 12 16:13 Folder
```

All users in LDAP. *gentent group* work fine, and get all users correct.

```
root@nexenta:/tmp# getent group | grep 1048
mygroupname::1048:a_ay,fred,john,superman
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you are using NFSv3 which underlying protocol limits to 16 the number of groups a user can belong to.

See that [blog](http://nfsworld.blogspot.fr/2005/03/whats-deal-on-16-group-id-limitation.html) for an explanation.